# App Engine API ERROR: 'appengine.applications.create' is required. [Owner role]

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy an app however, I get

PERMISSION_DENIED: Operation not allowed
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo
  description: The "appengine.applications.create" permission is required.
  resourceType: gae.api

I am getting this error even though I am the owner of the project and have access to all APIs.

Comment: Edit your question with the following: 1) What command did you execute? 2) What credentials are you using? Check with `gcloud auth list`. Then go to the Google Console and verify that credential has permissions (correct roles).

Comment: @JohnHanley I was on the logged in on the wrong account. Using the auth list command helped. Thank you!! I am new to GCP lol

Comment: I have written a few articles on Google credentials. Here are two examples that might help you. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-setting-up-gcloud-with-service-account-credentials/ and https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-understanding-gcloud-configurations/